# Django middleware is ImproperlyConfigured?

Tags: python, django, django-middleware

For some reason, I am getting an ImproperlyConfigured error on account of custom middleware.

```
[Wed Nov 07 20:47:07 2012] [error] [client 158.130.107.158] File does not exist: /home/davidxu/public_html/favicon.ico
[Wed Nov 07 20:47:09 2012] [error] [client 158.130.107.158] mod_wsgi (pid=24114): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/home/davidxu/dev/Penn-Course-Review-api/api/django.wsgi'.
[Wed Nov 07 20:47:09 2012] [error] [client 158.130.107.158] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Wed Nov 07 20:47:09 2012] [error] [client 158.130.107.158]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 219, in __call__
[Wed Nov 07 20:47:09 2012] [error] [client 158.130.107.158]     self.load_middleware()
[Wed Nov 07 20:47:09 2012] [error] [client 158.130.107.158]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 47, in load_middleware
[Wed Nov 07 20:47:09 2012] [error] [client 158.130.107.158]     raise exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured('Error importing middleware %s: "%s"' % (mw_module, e))
[Wed Nov 07 20:47:09 2012] [error] [client 158.130.107.158] ImproperlyConfigured: Error importing middleware api.apiconsumer.authenticate: "No module named api.apiconsumer.authenticate"
```

For reference, here are the relevant parts of the `settings.py` file:

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = ( 
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.cache.UpdateCacheMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.cache.FetchFromCacheMiddleware',
    'api.apiconsumer.authenticate.Authenticate',
)

INSTALLED_APPS = ( 
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'api.courses',
    'api.apiconsumer',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'api.static_content',
    'django_extensions', # used for debugging, remove if problematic
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable admin documentation:
    # 'django.contrib.admindocs',
)
```

And the `django.wsgi` file for what its worth. (Note, There is a lot of custom stuff in here.)

```
import os,sys

PROJECT_PATH = os.path.realpath(os.path.dirname(__file__))

sys.path.append(PROJECT_PATH)


from sandbox_config import *

#Uncomment these two lines to use virtualenv
#activate_this = os.path.join(COURSESAPI_APP_ROOT, "ENV/bin/activate_this.py")
#execfile(activate_this, dict(__file__=activate_this))

sys.path.append(DEV_ROOT)
sys.path.append(COURSESAPI_APP_ROOT)

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'settings'

import django.core.handlers.wsgi
application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
```

Unfortunately, at this point I'm not really sure what to try. The error is extremely unhelpful.

- Deleting the line in question caused the next custom middleware to break the program, which makes me think it may be a path issue.
- Google doesn't seem to have much in the way of help.

Any ideas what the issue may be and what's worth trying?

Comment: Did this work locally, but not on the server?

Comment: Our development process is to develop on the server, so there is no way to distinguish.

Comment: Where is the `wsgi` file in relation to the api/ director?

Comment: `wsgi` is directly inside `api` (`api/django.wsgi`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do the following files exist?

```
api/__init__.py
api/apiconsumer/__init__.py
```

If not, then `api/apiconsumer/authenticate.py` won't be found.

Also, try removing `api` from the prefix in the `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES` and `INSTALLED_APPS`. So, you would have:

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    ...
    'apiconsumer.authenticate.Authenticate',
)

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    ...
    'courses',
    'apiconsumer',
    'static_content',
    ...
)
```

Comment: In regards to the first and second, yes-- the third does not exist at all. What makes you suspect it is needed?

Comment: Because `PROJECT_PATH = os.path.realpath(os.path.dirname(__file__))` adds `../api/` as a root in the python path. So, by doing `api.apiconsumer`, python was looking for `../api/api/apiconsumer/`

Answer (score 3):

Where is this file (`api/apiconsumer/authenticate.py`)

```
No module named api.apiconsumer.authenticate
```

located (can you tell us your absolute path to this file?)?

Is it actually located at `/home/davidxu/dev/Penn-Course-Review-api/api/apiconsumer/authenticate.py` ?

If it's not at the correct filesystem path in relation to your wsgi process' PYTHONPATH, it wouldn't be able to load the code in that module.

Also, is your "api" app listed in your settings.py's `INSTALLED_APPS` ?  Django will not know to search for "api.apiconsumer.authenticate" if you did not list "api" as an `INSTALLED_APPS` app.

**EDITED**

OP informed me that `api` is actually the name of his project and his app name is `apiconsumer`.

So my response resolved the problem:-

I suggest you keep your django project name clearly separated from app names. So use `apiconsumer` as the app name in your INSTALLED_APPS and use `apiconsumer.authenticate.Authenticate` in your MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES.

Comment: The absolute path is :`/home/davidxu/dev/Penn-Course-Review-api/api/apiconsumer/authenticate.py`

Comment: typo? authenicate.py? ---> authenticate.py

Comment: See my updated answer about `api` being listed in `INSTALLED_APPS`?

Comment: `api` is not actually an app-- it is the name of the Django project, which happens to be inside of our main repo. Given that, our apps are all referred to as `api.X`

Comment: I suggest you keep your django project name clearly separated from app names. So use `apiconsumer` as the app name in your `INSTALLED_APPS` and use `apiconsumer.authenticate.Authenticate` in your `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES`.

Comment: It seems that renaming everything (deleting the `api` prefix) fixed it. Does that make sense to you? (That is, could you update your answer if it does?)

Answer (score 0):

I was getting improperly configured while using imports in **init**.py.

The symptoms were:
 - runserver works as a charm
 - while deployed (apache/nginx+uwsgi) there are numerous errors with importing modules and finally ImproperlyConfigured is raised

The solution:
Leave all **init**.py files empty.